# Plugin in Nagios does not work when using paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko, nagios

We're experiencing some strange issues with Nagios. We wrote a script in Python which uses paramiko, httplib and re. When we comment out the code that is written to use paramiko the script returns OK in Nagios. When we uncomment the script the status just returns (null).

This is our code

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
#ssh.connect(self.get('hostname'),int(self.get('port')),self.get('username'),allow_agent=True)
ssh.connect('192.168.56.102' , 22 , 'oracle' ,allow_agent=True)
link = '127.0.0.1:4848'
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget --no-proxy ' + link + ' 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error"')
result = stdout.readlines()
result = " ".join(result)

if result == "":
    return MonitoringResult(MonitoringResult.OK,'Webservice up')
else:
    return MonitoringResult(MonitoringResult.CRITICAL,'Webservice down %s' % result)
```

So when we comment out the part above

```
if result =="":
```

and add result="" above the if, it will just return 'Webservice up' in Nagios. When we enable the code above the if it will just return (null). Is there a conflict with paramiko or something?

When running the code in terminal it just returns the correct status but it doesn't show when implemented in Nagios

Answer (score 0):

I found that although nagios runs as effective user `"nagios"` it is using the environment settings for user `"root"` and not able to read the root private key to make the connection.

Adding `key_filename='/nagiosuserhomedir/.ssh/id_dsa'` to the options for `ssh.connect()` solved this same problem for me (pass the private key for nagios user explicitly in the code).